# Mobile application with compatibility issues on older operating systems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio in a project with the following configuration:

```
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.0.4
Gradle Version: 7.0.2
Compile SDK Version: 28
Build Tools Version: 28.0.3
```

The problem is that this application when installed on the mobile phone only works on operating systems such as android 9 or android 10 and on mobile with operating system 6.0.1 it does not work, **how do I make the application work on mobiles with older operating systems?**

- build.gradle (:app)

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdk 32
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.mps"
            minSdk 16
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
        implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: You have defined `minSdk 16` so the app can be installed on older devices. To make it run look at the error you get and adapt the code accordingly. For older devices you may need to implements special code blocks that are only executed on older devices. As your question misses any detail on the error you get we can't help you with that. BTW: Don' use comments for new info, edit your question instead - Stackoverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @Robert the application does not open on older android operating systems.

Comment: Most likely the do open but after a few milliseconds crash. Therefore please get the stacktrace of the crash and post it. => `adb logcat`